# Magento 2 : How to Create Brand

Tags: magento2, module, footer, manufacturer

I want to create separate brand. So I can list it on footer page in a tree listing of all brands. 
Is there any built in functionality or can anyone explain me how to create manufacturer/brand in Magento2. 
I cant find any way to create brand/manufacturer in magento2 as it was in prestashop.
Do I need module to create separate brand or I can create manually in magento2. 
I want to list my top brands in footer section.